# Where can I obtain a list of all virtual packages provided by a Ubuntu distribution / release (e.g. bionic)?

Tags: apt, package-management, aptitude, metapackages

1. At https://packages.ubuntu.com/, we follow the link "bionic" under "**Browse through the lists of packages:**".
2. At https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/, we follow the link "Virtual packages".
3. We reach https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/virtual/, but nothing is shown there (I think this is a bug!).

If we know the name of the virtual package (e.g. build-essential), we can display the information by manually typing the full URL, like the following:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/virtual/build-essential (same: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/build-essential)
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/virtual/xen-hypervisor (same: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xen-hypervisor)
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/virtual/xen-hypervisor-amd64 (same: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/xen-hypervisor-amd64)

This bothered me for 10+ years (since perhaps Ubuntu 6.06 or 8.04). Does anyone know where I can obtain a list of all virtual packages?

Thanks!

Comment: You can search for virtual packages using `aptitude` e.g. `aptitude search '?virtual'` - but `build-essential` isn't a actually virtual package AFAIK

Comment: @steeldriver : Thanks, it works! Yeah, I just found that `build-essential` is not a virtual package too. XD If you put this into the answer section, I will mark it as the accept answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `aptitude` package manager's search function can match virtual packages as follows:

```
aptitude search '?virtual'
```

However `build-essential` isn't such a package - in Debian terminology, a virtual package is described as follows:

> A virtual package is a generic name that applies to any one of a group
>   of packages, all of which provide similar basic functionality. For
>   example, both the konqueror and firefox-esr programs are web browsers,
>   and should therefore satisfy any dependency of a program that requires
>   a web browser on a system, in order to work or to be useful. They are
>   therefore both said to provide the "virtual package" called
>   www-browser.

So for example the virtual package `xserver` may be provided by any of

```
$ aptitude search '?provides(^xserver$)'
p   tigervnc-standalone-server                                              - Standalone virtual network computing server                                      
p   tigervnc-standalone-server:i386                                         - Standalone virtual network computing server                                      
p   tightvncserver                                                          - virtual network computing server software                                        
p   tightvncserver:i386                                                     - virtual network computing server software                                        
p   vnc4server                                                              - Virtual network computing server software                                        
p   vnc4server:i386                                                         - Virtual network computing server software                                        
p   xnest                                                                   - Nested X server                                                                  
p   xnest:i386                                                              - Nested X server                                                                  
p   xserver-xephyr                                                          - nested X server                                                                  
p   xserver-xephyr:i386                                                     - nested X server                                                                  
p   xserver-xephyr-hwe-18.04                                                - nested X server                                                                  
p   xserver-xephyr-hwe-18.04:i386                                           - nested X server                                                                  
i   xserver-xorg                                                            - X.Org X server                                                                   
p   xserver-xorg:i386                                                       - X.Org X server                                                                   
p   xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04                                                  - X.Org X server                                                                   
p   xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04:i386                                             - X.Org X server                                                                   
p   xvfb                                                                    - Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server                                              
p   xvfb:i386                                                               - Virtual Framebuffer 'fake' X server
```

Unfortunately I don't think there's a specific search term that would let you identify "packages like" `build-essential` - I've seen it sometimes referred to as a *dependency-only package*, but that's not strictly true since it does install some files of its own.

References:

- [The Debian GNU/Linux FAQ: What is a Virtual Package?](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkg_basics.en.html#s-virtual)
- [Aptitude: Search term reference](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html)